# How to connect mySQL running in a docker container to Ubuntu running in another docker container on windows?

Tags: mysql, docker

I have two docker containers on docker desktop on windows. One running mySQL and the other running ubuntu. I pulled both images using the respective docker pull command. I now want to run a script on the ubuntu container to modify the mySQL container. This is an example script

```
#!/bin/bash

# MAIN
test=$(sudo mysql -h localhost -uroot -proot myTestDB<<END
CREATE TABLE test_table (id int, text varchar(64));
END
)

echo $test
```

I want to execute this script in the ubuntu container, and it should create the table in the mySQL container. How can I create a bridge of sorts between the two containers?

These are the following commands that I am using:

- To open the mySQL container: `docker exec -it mySQLContainer bash` and then `mysql -uroot -p` and then I input my password.
- To open ubuntu: `docker exec -it myUbuntu bash`.

Comment: Did you link the containers properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They need to be in the **same** **network** in order to communicate.

To achieve that you could use `docker compose`.

If you define two services: (MySQL and Ubuntu)
By default, they would be in the same network.
`docker-compose.yaml`

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:latest

  os:
    image: ubuntu:latest
```

Then run

```
docker compose up -d
```

The manual way would be to create a common network `docker network create networkname` and use it during the creation of the running container `docker run --network networkname mysql`
This is that doing `docker compose` be default all services (container) would be under the same network.